# Webform Multiple File Upload Not Working Properly

Tags: webforms

I have a webform on my Drupal 10 site which has a multiple file upload element. When uploading multiple files, if I click "remove selected" an Ajax error is thrown. The items stay on the page visually, but If I click submit, the files will not be uploaded to the server, so they are still removed from the upload queue.

I've so far been able to recreate this by creating a new file upload element, and adding:

'#multiple': 10

to the YAML source. I'm just wondering if there are any known issues with removing files from a multiple file upload element?

Comment: To find out if there are known issues, you can search https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/search/webform

Comment: might help to post what "Ajax error is thrown" as it probably provides a clue.

Comment: A client error with a 400 response. I'm not too familiar with debugging ajax errors, but there didn't seem to be any clues in the console. There is also a jquery error, but that error only really returns the ajax and jquery versions used, which don't seem to be too useful.